# Type hinting and ctypes foreign functions

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, type-hinting, mypy

How should I type-hint a foreign function defined with Python's `ctypes`?

Do I need to repeat the information provided in the `restype` and `argtypes` attributes?  Or is there a method to enable mypy to somehow comprehend the attributes?

For example, given this function definiton:

```
    # Original function definition:

    libopus.opus_encode.restype = opus_int32
    libopus.opus_encode.argtypes = [oe_p, opus_int16_p, c_int, c_uchar_p, opus_int32]

    def opus_encode(st, pcm, frame_size, data, max_data_bytes):
        return libopus.opus_encode(st, pcm, frame_size, data, max_data_bytes)
```

Is the best approach to manually duplicate the type information?

```
    # Duplicated type specification:

    libopus.opus_encode.restype = opus_int32
    libopus.opus_encode.argtypes = [oe_p, opus_int16_p, c_int, c_uchar_p, opus_int32]

    def opus_encode(st: oe_p, 
                    pcm: opus_int16_p, 
                    frame_size: c_int, 
                    data: c_uchar_p, 
                    max_data_bytes: opus_int32) -> opus_int32:
        return libopus.opus_encode(st, pcm, frame_size, data, max_data_bytes)
```

Or is there a better approach?